# scheduling of the jobs with crontab in linux

Tags: linux, cron

existing system:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.18-398.el5`
$ uname
Linux
```

I want to schedule one of my shell script  10-10am.

i am using `crontab -e`

press I to get insert mode

```
10 10 * * * /home/oracle/sample.sh
```

crontab is scheduling the job at 10-10am.

when i migrate the same jobs to the production i found crontab is not scheduling the jobs.

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64`
$ uname
Linux
```

i can not able to found any log file.crontab is not initializing the job.

appreciate the valuable time and helping hands.

Comment: Your cron job looks fine to me. What's the full output of `crontab -l` on your production server?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cron daemon is not reading.

The cron daemon is the one that looks for the /etc/crontab file and spawn the processes.

You can see if it is running, as simple as:

```
$ ps aux | grep cron
root      1090  0.0  0.0   6784  3776 ?        Ss   Apr06   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

or

```
$ systemctl status cron
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-04-06 15:26:33 EDT; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1090 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─1090 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

If the daemon is not running, you can invoke it using:

```
# systemctl start cron
```